# How can I get selected text in pdf in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome Extention to manipulate pdf file so I want to get selected text in the pdf. How can I do that.

Some thing like that:

[image]

Comment: maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text

Comment: I have tried it, It doesn't work with pdf.

Comment: Why this question is down voted

Comment: It's possible, because some chrome extensions can definitely do this. For example, the Google Scholar extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the internal [undocumented commands](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:chrome/browser/resources/pdf/pdf_scripting_api.js) of the built-in PDF viewer.

Here's an example of a content script:

```
function getPdfSelectedText() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    window.addEventListener('message', function onMessage(e) {
      if (e.origin === 'chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai' &&
          e.data && e.data.type === 'getSelectedTextReply') {
        window.removeEventListener('message', onMessage);
        resolve(e.data.selectedText);
      }
    });
    // runs code in page context to access postMessage of the embedded plugin
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    if (chrome.runtime.getManifest().manifest_version > 2) {
      script.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('query-pdf.js');
    } else {
      script.textContent = `(${() => {
        document.querySelector('embed').postMessage({type: 'getSelectedText'}, '*');
      }})()`;
    }
    document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
    script.remove();
  });
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (msg === 'getPdfSelection') {
    getPdfSelectedText().then(sendResponse);
    return true;
  }
});
```

This example assumes you send a message from the popup or background script:

```js
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, ([tab]) => {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, 'getPdfSelection', sel => {
    // do something
  });
});
```

See also [How to open the correct devtools console to see output from an extension script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913799/how-to-open-the-correct-devtools-console-to-see-output-from-an-extension-script)

#### ManifestV3 extensions also need this:

- manifest.json should expose query-pdf.js

  ```json
    "web_accessible_resources": [{
      "resources": ["query-pdf.js"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "use_dynamic_url": true
    }]
  ```
- query-pdf.js

  ```js
  document.querySelector('embed').postMessage({type: 'getSelectedText'}, '*')
  ```

Comment: This did not work for me. The message listener did not intercept any events from the pdf viewer, unfortunately.

Comment: @AlexZhong, this is still working so if you can post a new question with an [MCVE](/help/mcve) that describes all the specifics of your case someone (or I) might be able to help. Note that this answer only works with the built-in viewer and only in the main page, so for an iframe you would need to make a couple of changes.

Comment: Hey, I tried it with the built-in viewer. What I did was I copied your code in my CRX, tried in both the background and content script separately -> the message listener is registered -> I cannot observe any messages received from the listener when I select the text in the pdf viewer.

Comment: Also, I could not find any "getPdfSelection" message being sent in the source code that you linked

Comment: You are supposed to send that message yourself, of course.

Comment: Is there a way to listen for a text selection and trigger it this way?

Comment: This works for a pdf file served on the web ( https:// blabla ), but I couldn't make it work for a local file. It says: "Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null')." (manifest file is configured as instructed)

Answer (score 0):

There is no one generic solution for all pdf extensions.
Every extention has is own API.
If you work with google-chrome extension i belive it's impossible.

[How to get the selected text from an embedded pdf in a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765844/how-to-get-the-selected-text-from-an-embedded-pdf-in-a-web-page)

[How extension get the text selected in chrome pdf viewer？](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15527095/)