# Using content scripts in a Chrome Extension is there any way to get the user's selection in a PDF preview or Google Doc?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I understand how to use window.getSelection().toString() to get the user's selection in a 'regular' (plain vanilla) website via a Chrome Extension and a content script.

Is it possible to achieve the same goal in more complex websites? Like a Google Doc, PDF preview (via Chrome browser), or other embedded/iframed/complex renderers?

Appreciations for any suggestions/direction.

Comment: It is possible but you'll need to investigate this for each site individually and possibly reverse-engineer the page scripts, there is no universal solution. For PDF viewer, see [How can I get selected text in pdf in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61076939)

Comment: Many thanks, as always! Was kind of afraid of that answer but makes sense.