# Is it possible to differentiate Kami texts and normal texts on a PDF

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-classroom

I am working on a project for my school and I am trying to create a tool that can help teachers grade homework quicker with a homework grader. I was thinking of trying to find a way to differentiate normal texts vs texts/work created through Kami. Kami is a google extension that my school is using to allow students to submit work on already created PDFs. I am planning to locate each Kami texts and match it with the answer choices in order given by the teachers. However, I don't know if it is possible to scan a document and pick out only the Kami text. Thanks.

Comment: make sure to include the problem statement, current progress, current output and expected output to the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. To access the PDF **directly** you'll have to use the undocumented internal commands of the built-in PDF viewer ([example for getSelectedText](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61076939/)). You can try extracting the entire text by using the other commands from the [source code](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:chrome/browser/resources/pdf/pdf_scripting_api.js) of Chromium, inspect it yourself.
2. An alternative method is to download the PDF from its URL (using the standard `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch`, [more info](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr)) and use some javascript library to parse the file.

Answer (score 0):

CEO of Kami here. This is a great question, and one that I'm happy to help you if you reach out to me (email is first name at kamiapp.com)

But to answer your question, Kami creates [PDF-spec compliant text annotations](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2018/what-are-annotations/) when we embed our text boxes into the PDF. You can tell it's created with Kami because it's annotation object also includes a dictionary key "KAMI:comment_b64" or "KAMI:comment" in legacy cases. It's value includes a Base64 encoded string that you can decode to get a JSON object of the annotation.

Essentially you can decode it's data by doing this in Javascript:

```
var b64str = dict.get('KAMI:comment_b64');
var kamiComment = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(escape(atob(b64str))));
```

Or with this:

```
var kamiComment = JSON.parse(dict.get('KAMI:comment'));
```