# Is there a javascript event to detect when a pdf is finished loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to detect when my Chrome browser is finished loading a remote pdf, for instance from https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.11353.pdf

The context is I'm working on a chrome extension and I'd like the `content_script` to execute some things only *after* the pdf is downloaded and displayed.

I'm open to using JQuery but

```
$(() => {})
```

is triggered too early and things like

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    alert("Hello")
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    alert("Hello")
});
```

Are not triggered at all

Comment: So if I understand you correctly the answer is no?

Comment: PDF files are loaded by an internal PDF viewer (in Chrome) which is not related to standard DOM events. It exposes a custom `documentLoaded` event which you can observe by reworking [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61076939).