# Can inject a script to file uri scheme

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, uri, microsoft-edge, add-on

i'm trying to create a microsoft edge extension to save pdf edits automatically. Can i inject a script to a file uri scheme. ie, file:///example.pdf. ([this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ2j4.png) is my browser screenshot).
There is a save button on right-top of the screen.i want to autoclick that button when an edit occurs.but i need to inject a file to that tab.
what code should i include in manifest file?

or any of the browser will support this feature?

Comment: Extensions can't click this button because the viewer is a part of the built-in UI.

Comment: @wOxxOm why i can't inject a js script into this tab? does file:///  uri scheme support script injections?

Comment: The UI of the viewer is not accessible for extensions. It's not a part of the page.

Comment: @wOxxOm is there any solution for this?

Comment: No, there isn't, but if you're lucky the viewer may expose the save command via its [undocumented API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61076939), which is up to you to explore.