# copy the ms-egde pdf-viewer's source code from the devTools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, microsoft-edge

I want to develop the pdf reader on MS-EDGE as a browser extension.

But in this reader, no extensions can be enabled.

But I found that through devtools, I can get the source code of this reader.

So I want to copy the code directly into my extension for secondary development.

Is this possible and legal?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think its not possible because. its not open source.
browser extensions are not supported in file:/// uri scheme
i have also asked about this :

1. [Can inject a script to file uri scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71939341/can-inject-a-script-to-file-uri-scheme)
2. [how to inject code in file uri scheme for microsoft edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75025391/how-to-inject-code-in-file-uri-scheme-for-microsoft-edge)